Please help me choosing license for open hardware project
I need a license that:
a) allows distribution remixes under different license;
b) allows any usage of the project, even for commercial purposes;
c) requires original author attribution;
d) suitable for licensing all parts of my project (schematic, PCB, documentation).
In other words, license like CC BY, but which is suitable for hardware projects.

This question is similar to: Using CC BY 4.0 license for my open hardware project. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ThomasOwens Question you mentioned is asking about specific license, I need to select license that different from CC BY (CC BY is not suitable for licensing hardware project)

@t1m013y I think the confusion here is why you have asked two questions, one asking if you can use CC-BY for your hardware project and this one where you are categorically stating CC-BY is not suitable for a hardware project. Could you clarify which question you need answered?

Philip is completely right.  Please decide which of the questions you want answered, and close the other.  Otherwise, one of them may get closed by the community in the immediate future.

There are at least three Open Source Initiative (OSI) approved licenses for open source hardware:

CERN Open Hardware Licence Version 2 – Permissive
CERN Open Hardware Licence Version 2 – Weakly Reciprocal
CERN Open Hardware Licence Version 2 – Strongly Reciprocal

The CERN OHL permissive license would be equivalent to CC BY.
Collectively, these are known as the CERN Open Hardware Licenses (OHL) version 2.
The OHL rationale document and FAQ will help you to understand them.
The three licenses even have their own SPDX short identifiers viz. CERN-OHL-P-2.0, CERN-OHL-W-2.0 and CERN-OHL-S-2.0.
Additional questions in the comments from OP:

Does this license exactly match my requirements: a) allows
distribution remixes under different license; b) allows any usage of
the project, even for commercial purposes;
c) requires original author attribution?

Condition (a) is met by CERN-OHL-P-2.0 section 3.4:

3.4 You may Convey Covered Source or modified Covered Source under licence terms which differ from the terms of this Licence provided
that You:
a) comply at all times with subsection 3.3; and
b) provide a copy of this Licence to anyone to whom You Convey Covered
Source or modified Covered Source.

Conditions (a) and (b) are met by the FAQ statement:

CERN-OHL-P is a permissive licence. It allows people to take your
code, relicense it and use it without
any obligation to distribute the
sources when they ship a product.

Condition (c) is met by CERN-OHL-P-2.0 sections 3.2 and 3.3:

3.2 You may modify Covered Source, other than Notices.
You may only delete Notices if they are no longer applicable to the
corresponding Covered Source as modified by You and You may add
additional Notices applicable to Your modifications.
3.3 You may Convey modified Covered Source (with the effect that You shall also become a Licensor) provided that You:
a) retain Notices as required in subsection 3.2; and
b) add a Notice to the modified Covered Source stating that You have
modified it, with the date and brief description of how You have
modified it.


Please explain me why does CERN-OHL-P 2.0 asks to "provide a copy of this Licence to anyone to whom You Convey Covered Source or modified Covered Source" even if modification is licensed under different license?

@t1m013y That's for attribution.

Does this license exactly match my requirements: a) allows distribution remixes under different license; b) allows any usage of the project, even for commercial purposes; c) requires original author attribution?

@t1m013y Updated answer. Please take a look at it.

Thanks. (Maybe) last question: does CERN-OHL-P 2.0 allow usage of licensed material as part of proprietary project?

@t1m013y Yes, it does. It states that in the quoted FAQ statement: "CERN-OHL-P is a permissive licence. It allows people to take your code, relicense it and use it without any obligation to distribute the sources when they ship a product."

Thanks. I accepted your answer.
